# Separating a CSV file into separate arrays

Tags: objective-c, arrays, csv, nsstring, nsarray

Ok, to begin i am a beginner so i'm still learning.
so i have this file with world cities. It looks like this:

```
     City,Country,Latitude,Longitude
     Aberdeen, Scotland,57.15,-2.15
     Adelaide, Australia,-34.91666667,138.6
     Algiers, Algeria,36.83333333,3
     Amsterdam, Netherlands,52.36666667,4.883333333
     Ankara, Turkey,39.91666667,32.91666667
     AsunciÛn, Paraguay,-25.25,-57.66666667
     Athens, Greece,37.96666667,23.71666667
     Auckland, New Zealand,-36.86666667,174.75
     Bangkok, Thailand,13.75,100.5
```

I have to put all these files into separate parallel arrays, I'm suppose to calculate the distances using the latitude and longitude, thats not a big deal, the thing is i want to put them into a C-style Array and i don't how to do that in Objective C. I know you can use NSArray but that doesn't seem to work for me. how can i do this in Objective c. i already read the file into an NSString by doing

```
     anotherLine = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:docDirectory encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:nil];
```

//docDirectory is where my file is

How can i put this NSString into 4 separate arrays (cities[max],countries[max], latitude[max], longitude[max]) .
And again, i'm still a beginner on objective c, i do know some stuff on c++ so i'm trying to make it as close to c as possible.

Comment: Read the NSString spec -- componentsSeparatedByString, et al.

Comment: @HotLicks can you give me an example?

Comment: Can you read the spec?  First split into lines, then each line into columns, then assign column values to their individual arrays.  Very straightforward, and everything you need is right there in the NSString spec (plus NSMutableArray, probably).

Comment: (Not to mention that this is a common question, so there are probably 30 good examples here if you look for them.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this :

```
NSMutableArray* cities = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray* countries = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray* latitude = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray* longitude = [NSMutableArray array];

// read everything from text
NSString* fileContents =
[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:docDirectory encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:nil];

// first, separate by new line
NSArray* allLinedStrings =
[fileContents componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
 [NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];


[allLinedStrings enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if (idx > 0) //Ignore first line column header
    {
        NSArray* columnsFile = [((NSString*)obj) componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
        [cities addObject:[columnsFile objectAtIndex:0]];
        [countries addObject:[columnsFile objectAtIndex:1]];
        [latitude addObject:[columnsFile objectAtIndex:2]];
        [longitude addObject:[columnsFile objectAtIndex:3]];
    }
}];
```

Comment: can you explain the enumarateObjectsUsingBlock method to me?

Comment: it's equivalent a for statement read NSArray Apple doc https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html

Comment: @Juan - It's an obfuscated `for` loop.

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: the columnsFile array is not correctly set, place a breakpoint in first line of if block and check it

Comment: @tdelepine: Thats why I edited your post and added a check for [columnsFile count] ...

Comment: @Schulze Thomas: I seen your edit, but it's a consumer convenience. I prefer thrown an exception that return nothing in silent mode

Comment: My code works my code responds to the specified exigences. If you want add some tests or raising exceptions you wil note it !!